# PostGis : Geometry type (LineString) does not match column type (Polygon)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm a bit lost in this case.

Let me explain: I'm currently doing a query on a table and strangely I got this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidParameterValue) Geometry type (LineString) does not match column type (Polygon)
```

However my table and her data are not supposed to have LineString element in it (however, data is not generated by me so a mistake can be there ).
So I don't how to found the bad boy who causing this or to treat this.

The table data his coming from has this structure (we call it table_1) :

```
created_on         |         updated_on         |   id  | polygon
```

The new table data (we call it table_2) :

```
created_on         |         updated_on         |   id  | polygon
```

To check if one of the data was LineString, I try this query:

```
SELECT count(id)  FROM table_1 WHERE ST_GeometryType(polygon::geometry)='ST_LineString';
 count
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

And to be sure I perform the same query on the logical geometry which should be there, and I get this :

```
SELECT count(id)  from table_1 WHERE ST_GeometryType(polygon::geometry)='ST_Polygon';
 count
-------
  5191
(1 row)
```

```
SELECT count(*)  from table_1 ;
 count
-------
  5191
(1 row)
```

So I'm a bit lost, thanks everyone for them helps
If I made a stupid error let me know haha

Comment: What does this query return: `SELECT count(id)  from table_1 WHERE ST_GeometryType(polygon::geometry)<>'ST_Polygon';`? or even `SELECT ST_GeometryType(polygon::geometry), count(id) 
FROM table_1 
GROUP BY ST_GeometryType(polygon::geometry);`

Comment: Can you show the SQL statement that returns this error?

Comment: Hi @JimJones , thanks for the answer , the first query return : count 0 , and the second query return      st_geometrytype | count
-----------------+-------
 ST_Polygon      |  5191
(1 row)                              One of my supposition is that a change is done during my query which gives me the error (I'm linking multipolygon to get a single polygon) maybe here an error on coordinates create a LineString, I will perform other test

Comment: @fabienhell so the error has to be somewhere else.. I mean, not in the database ;-) Check if you're querying the right database and if somehow an uninvited LineString has arrived in your party :-)